# Journey Builder Entry event

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

I have a Journey built in JB and I want to add people to it from a DE. A SQL query will run every day and then the contents of that DE joins the journey.
I've tried this and when I run the event all the contacts get 'EventQueuedForProcessing' as their status (even after a few hours). I've popped a ticket in to SF but wanted to see if anyone has encountered this or knows a fix?

Also, do users need to stay in a DE for the entirety of the Journey. If somebody begins a journey and is then removed from the associated DE what happens?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your first question, I have seen this behavior before and it's usually related to an issue with an incident on the queues used by Journey Builder. This usually fixes itself after a few hours once the queues have cleared, but worth checking with support to see if there are any current incidents or check http://trust.marketingcloud.com to see if there are incidents on your stack.

To answer your second question, you can eject a Contact from an Interaction by:

1. Creating a Decision Split Activity (or Activities) in your Interaction to route Contacts to an empty branch if they meet the criteria
2. Create a Goal in the Interaction to defined the criteria when a Contact should exit the Interaction and in the final Summary step, enable the exit option: 'When the customer reaches this Goal, they will exit the Interaction.'

To answer your third question, if you remove a Contact from the Event Source Data Extension, this will not eject them from the Interaction. Once a Contact is injected into an Interaction, they will continue moving through it.

Comment: Thank so much for this. Still getting an error on the event (24 hours after it starting), will chase up SF.